# JQuery UI Autocomplete : How To Make It Not Editable?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

This given code is actually what I need for my project : 
http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#multiple but I need to go more with it.

how to make the selected value become un-editable by user? because if you type 'j' it will show you 'jquery', but before you submit to the server you're still be able to edit that selected value 'jquery' with something else. for example 'jqqqq' and you can submit to the server.

this will cause problems on server point of view. so how to make user so they have no choice to edit the value but still can delete it. just like 'TAGS' input in this StackOverflow. thanks.

Comment: Try the multiple select option of chosen: http://harvesthq.github.com/chosen/

Comment: wow!!! that's another cool things to do... I'll give a try right away... +1 for you bro...